# Error Customize errorhandling in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-error-pages

in asp.net webform when I want to customize the error page I use the following comment :

```
<customErrors mode="on" defaultRedirect="defaultError.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="pageNotFound.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Although there are error pages, unfortunately it does not work and still displays the error text.

[image]

I want to customize the error page but command not working...

Comment: `mode=""` is **case-sensitive**: it needs to be `mode="On"`, not `mode="on"`.